# Are these sentences considered grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

So here is the question:

*His eyes, still on me, were blazing with fury.*

I know for sure this sentence is correct. But what about these:

*Still on me, his eyes were blazing with fury.*   and

*His eyes were blazing with fury, still on me.*

These sentences look quite unnatural to me, even clumsy. Can you guys tell me if these sentences are correct?

Comment: Third one is wrong.  Needs to be:  *His eyes, blazing with fury, were still on me.* ***or*** *His eyes were blazing with fury **and** [were] still on me.*

Comment: So the second one is right?

Comment: Yes. Now, consider the grammaticality of this: "His eyes were still on me, blazing with fury."

Comment: Ok. I must admit that sounds better. But why is third one wrong and second one is right?

Comment: *Still on me* is an example of a nonrestrictive clause (see link at the end of this comment). Nonrestrictive clauses modify that which they are adjacent to. So the second example is correct because *still on me* is modifying *his eyes*; the third example is incorrect because *still on me* is modifying *fury.* http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-participial-phrases

Comment: I should add that the third example constitutes a dangling modifier: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/597/01/

Comment: In general, when using a phrase such as "still on me", you want the referenced thing to be clearly apparent.  Basically this means as close as possible to the thing ("his eyes") being referenced, and preferably after rather than before.  Note that with your third example the reader is left to wonder whether it's "his eyes" or "fury" that is still on you.  In the second example the reader must read "still on me" and file that thought away until "his eyes" is read, to know what you're talking about.

Comment: I disagree, when I read the second sentence I always read it as a man is physically lying on top of someone while their eyes blaze with fury.

Answer (score 0):

> Still on me, his eyes were blazing with fury.

This sentence is kosher, but I agree it sounds clumsy.  I suppose it's because it starts out with a static feeling, perhaps because of the other possible meaning of *still* (not moving).  This contradicts the feeling of movement in *blazing with fury* -- for example, flames dancing in a fire.

The first sentence, *His eyes, still on me, were blazing with fury," works so much better because the focus remains more clearly on *his eyes.*

> His eyes were blazing with fury, still on me.

As someone explained in a comment, in this case, "still on me" would be describing *fury*, which doesn't quite work.  "Still aimed at me" would work, technically, although in the context this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I don't think any difference between static and motion is behind why that version sounds so clumsy. Consider that if you switch the two descriptors, it's must more natural-sounding: “Still blazing with fury, his eyes were on me”. I think it's more that beginning a sentence with a whiz-deleted nonrestrictive clause with no verbal constituent (in the shape of a participle) tends to sound clumsy, especially is there's an adverb present as well.